# custom comparison method for c++ map based on key and value

Tags: c++, stl, maps

I searched a lot but I didnt find the answer I want.

I need to sort c++ map based on keys and values.
something like this method :

```
bool mycomp(mii::iterator a, mii::iterator b) {
    if (a->second > b->second)
        return true;
    else if (a->second < b->second)
        return false;
    else
        return a->first > a->second;
}
```

and use it something like that

```
sort(m.begin() , m.end(), mycomp);
```

where m is :

```
map<int,int> m;
```

can I do such thing ? if yes, what should be the correct syntax.

Comment: You cannot "sort" a map, since a map is not a sequence.

Comment: @KerrekSB This is incorrect. ````std::map```` contents are sorted by ````std::less<key>```` by default, but a custom comparator can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the `std::map` you can provide a `Compare` function as a template parameter. See [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for more details.

However, I believe this is only for key sorting. Key-value sorting is not inherit to the map structure (i.e. what happens if the value changes?)

Comment: mascoj is correct here; the compare function is only passed the keys.  Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map